# Cycle class on group of element with a link

Tags: jquery

How do I cycle a class on set of elements on clicking a link. 
Here's what the HTML looks like:

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</section>
<a href="#">Iterate Class on Items</a>
```

JS:

```
$('a').click(function() {
     $('.container .item').each(function() {
          //cycle .active class on click
     });
});
```

Comment: You want to add the class `active` or check if it has class `active`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $('a').click(function() {
     // Activate next
     $('.container .item.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active'); 
     // If none are active, activate first
     if ($('.container .item.active').length == 0) 
         $('.container .item').slice(0,1).addClass('active'); 
    });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TMEne/